# IE7 elements in box not floating right

Tags: html, css, css-float, internet-explorer-7

I've got a problem with an absolutely positioned `<div>` in IE7 where it's breaking the list right in the middle. I've tried just about everything I can think of to get the 3 elements aligned but I can't get it working in IE7.

The `<span>` (and I've tried it as a `<p>`) always wraps down in IE7 as it's the last member of the div. You can see it for yourself at: http://lifeproject.amdesign.com. It's in the lower right hand corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a width to `ul#footer_links`. It would solve your problem. IE7 keep width maximum when element is floated
I added this rule and it fixed:

`ul#footer_links{width:140px}`

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: inline-block` with ie7 fix instead of `float: right`:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not mention `right` and `top` property where you are giving positioning absolute. ie 7 render position absolute by default in middle. please give them `top` and `right` depend on your requirement.